# No voice is recording while a file is saved

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, mediarecorder

I am trying to make call recorder in it everything is working fine I am getting file of the audio too but when I try to listen to it I can't able to here the voices here my code friends please help me out I cant able to understand the error.

Broadcastreceiver.java

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaRecorder startrecording;
    boolean recordstarted = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        startrecording = new MediaRecorder();
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startrecording.reset();
            startrecording.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            startrecording.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            startrecording.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            startrecording.setOutputFile("/sdcard/sample.3gp");
            startrecording.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
                    Log.d("Error",mediaRecorder.toString()+" "+String.valueOf(i)+" "+String.valueOf(i1));
                }
            });
            startrecording.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
                    Log.d("info",mediaRecorder.toString()+" "+String.valueOf(i)+" "+String.valueOf(i1));
                }
            });
            try {
                startrecording.prepare();
                startrecording.start();
                recordstarted = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Idle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (recordstarted) {
                startrecording = new MediaRecorder();
                startrecording.stop();
                startrecording.reset();
                startrecording.release();
                recordstarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.prominere.prominere.incomingcall">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: AFAIK, Android does not allow to record call due to legal issue.

Comment: but we are app like call recorder from play stores na

Comment: Android doesn't do anything to prevent voice call recording, so I'm not sure where this legal issue claim comes from (if this has indeed changed recently, then please provide a link to the relevant commit(s)). The thing is, Android itself doesn't implement any voice call recording functionality, because it's a platform-dependent feature. So it's up to the platform provider and/or OEM to implement that functionality. Some do, some don't. Have you tried recording just the UPLINK or DOWNLINK audio to see if that works?

Comment: yes i had tried them